# can't call the custom field on custom visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, dml

i m trying to learn about visualforce page based on my understanding, after reading the material from web and workbooks. I created an C.Object called Book__c and calling custom fields to a visualforce page. I have controller where i m using a soql query to get the fields to use in my vf page. Can anybody tell me what i m doing wrong?

### Error:

Error: Unknown property 'testController.Describe__c'

-----------------------------------vfpage--------------------------------------

```
<apex:page controller="testController" sidebar="false" showHeader="true" standardStylesheets="true">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}! " >

    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Testing picklist values with dependent list">
        <apex:inputtext value='{!Describe__c}' />
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
   <apex:detail subject="{!account.ownerId}" relatedList="true" />
</apex:page>
```

---

### and here is my controller

```
public class testController {

        public Book__c myBook {get; set;}


    public testController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    myBook = new Book__c();
    myBook = [SELECT books__c,Describe__c,Id,Name,OwnerId,RecordTypeId FROM Book__c];

    }

    public testController(){


    }

    //mylist = new list<Book__c>();



    public pageReference cancel(){

    Id fId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    pageReference p = new pageReference('/a00/o');
    return p;
    }

    public pageReference save(){
    pageReference p;
    String Rtype = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Rtype');
    myBook.RecordTypeId = Rtype;
    insert myBook;
    return p;
    }
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Describe__c is a field on the Book__c myBook property of the controller.  You must access it in your Visualforce page through the myBook property:

```
<apex:inputtext value='{!myBook.Describe__c}' />
```

Comment: Sure! Glad to help. You were really close. :-)